# If $T$ is an linear bijective isometry, is it true that $T^{-1}$ an isometry?

Tags: proof-verification, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, isometry

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces. Let $T:X \rightarrow Y$ be a linear bijective isometry.

> Question: Is it true that $T^{-1}$ also an isometry?

I think the answer is yes.

My attempt: We want to show that for any $y \in Y,$ we have 
$$\| T^{-1}y\| = \|y \|.$$
Since $T$ is an isometry, we have 
$$\| y \| = \| T T^{-1}y \| = \| T^{-1}y\|.$$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Yes, that's good.

Comment: the linear condition can be removed from both the map and space.

Comment: So the correct statement is bijective isometry will have isometry inverse?